# Sending data from app to php form using post method, or just use get?

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, post, get

Hi there and thank you for taking the time to read this.

I have been searching all throughout this website but none of the answers work for me.

What I am trying to do:

I'm am trying to take a username and a password from a user and send it to a php script over the post method seeing as it is more secure, (I think?) which will eventually hash them and pop them into a nice little table in a MySql database.

What I have done:

I have been able to get this to work, but only through the GET method. I think post is more secure, but even if they are the same, this could just be a learning exercise.

I'm relatively new to xcode but I can sort of understand it when I look at it.. :P

Thanks again for reading this topic.

Sincerely.

EDIT:

Here is the code.. :P

NSLog(@"Username entered = %@",usernameField.text);
            NSLog(@"Password entered = %@", passwordField.text);

```
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://localhost:8888/login.php?username=%@&password=%@", usernameField.text, passwordField.text];
    NSLog(@"Url accessed = %@", strURL);

    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"success"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];
        [loginActivityView stopAnimating];
        usernameField.enabled = YES;
        passwordField.enabled = YES;
        passwordField.text = @"";
        buttonThatWasPressed.enabled = YES;
    }
```

Comment: xCode? Any code? Post something to show what you've done. BTW, POST is no more secure than GET.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it.. :P

Comment: Nice tagging. You specify the IDE you use but leave out the programming language you use. Makes no sense. And what does this question have to do with php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hii Frank Dixon First of all it wont work in local host it works only in remote host,you haven't posted your php codings i am not sure what process you are making,but hope this helps

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:strURL];
        NSURLRequest *request=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

        NSData *data1=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

        NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // NSLog(@"%@",str);

        NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON =[str JSONValue];

        // NSString *new=[responseJSON objectForKey:@"success"];
        if ([[responseJSON objectForKey:@"success"] intValue] == 1) {
            NSLog(@"success");

        }
```

and here i am receiving result as JSON values where php looks something like this in POST method

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['YOUR DATA']) ) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$addr1 = $_POST['YOUR DATA'];


// include db connect class
```

// require_once **DIR** . '/db_connect.php';

```
// connecting to db
//$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Db_name(name, YOUR DATA) VALUES('$name', '$addr1')");
```

hope this helps you....here return JSON value 1 for success so that you can process them in your project

Comment: That absolutely amazing!! Thank you very much for your help!!! Really appreciate it!!! :)